# Optimisation of threshold computation

Tags: c#, optimization, ternary-operator, threshold

I'm trying to optimise the following C# code, which sets bytes to `0x00` or `0xFF` based on a threshold.

```
for (int i = 0; i < veryLargeNumber; i++)
{
    data[i] = (byte)(data[i] < threshold ? 0 : 255);
}
```

Visual Studio's performance profiler shows that the above code is rather expensive, taking nearly 8 seconds to compute - 98% of my total processing expense. I'm processing just under a thousand items, so that adds up to over two hours.

I think the issue is to do with the ternary conditional operator, since it causes a branch. I'd imagine a pure-math operation of some sort could be significantly faster, since it's CPU-cache friendly.

Is there a way to optimise this? It's possible for me to fix the threshold value, if that helps. I'd consider anything above a ~7% performance increase a win, since that's a whole 10 minutes shaved off the total processing time.

Comment: did you look at the IL produced for this?

Comment: @DarenThomas Nope, and it wouldn't be much use to me either, since I don't know much about IL. If it were x86 assembly, however, I'd be fine! ^_^

Comment: they can't be *that* different ;) but the JIT should really be able to compile this down to really fast - could you try storing the result in a separate array? That might make optimization easier, since the optimizer doesn't have to worry about you altering the input array. But i'm talking about stuff i don't really understand here. i upvoted the advice for parallelism though, since this is a really easy case to parallelize!

Comment: I would try moving `(byte)` cast operator closer to the actual constants (0 and 255). This should help you avoiding casting in each iteration.

Comment: @Snowbear, actually, I'd be surprised if any casting is done at all - the compiler should be able to figure out that `0` and `255` are bytes.

Comment: @DarenThomas, agreed regarding IL. Not sure whether compiler will guess it or not, worth checking. `0b` and `255b` are not legal literals in C#.

Comment: Moving the cast seems to give a ~2% performance improvement. Might be incidental, but when 1% is more than a minute I'll take anything I can get :)

Comment: what is an actual `threshold` value you use? For example for 128 you can actually try bit manipulation as @Predrag suggested.

Comment: Moving the constant values into local-scoped byte variables gave me another 6% boost. I'm still a bit puzzled why this should be faster, but it is (reproducible on my PC). Thanks for posting this question btw :)

Comment: @Snowbear Right now it's 96, but I would prefer to keep it tweakable if possible. I could accept anything between 128 and 96 if a bit-banging solution can provide a significant performance boost.

Comment: @Gene Doing that causes a 6% performance loss for me. Perhaps it's a compiler quirk.

Comment: would using `int[]` instead of `byte[]` for `data` help?

Comment: @DarenThomas That was suggested by Makubex. It might make the operation slightly faster, but it consumes 4x the memory and has an overhead associated with memory allocation. As such, the benefit doesn't outweight the drawbacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using .NET 4.0 Framework, you could make use of Parallel  Library in following link,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717

In Your case, you must have to verify the threshold, anyway it would take time.  So make use of thread or lambda expressions

Comment: Don't know why I didn't think of using `Parallel` in the first place. It's now down to 5 seconds per item!

Answer (score 1):

Just to suggest, use bitwise operators for this purpose because they are faster, together with  parallel approach.

```
0x00 = 0000 0000 
0xFF = 1111 1111
```

Try with `OR` operator(i.e. `0 | 1 = 1` where `|` stands for `OR` operator

EDIT:

This is how you could compare which number is bigger:
let `a,b` be numbers:

```
int temp= a ^ b;
temp|= temp>> 1;
temp|= temp>> 2;
temp|= temp>> 4;
temp|= temp>> 8;
temp|= temp>> 16;

temp&= ~(temp>> 1) | 0x80000000;
temp&= (a ^ 0x80000000) & (b ^ 0x7fffffff);
```

Comment: I thought of bitwise operators, but couldn't come up with a scheme that resulted in 00000000 vs 11111111 based on an input and a threshold, without a branch.

Comment: My suggestion was given to decrease tome of assigning

Comment: Assignment is *significantly* faster than a bitwise operation.

Comment: @Polynomial, I think we should compare `bitwise operation` VS `if statement` instead of comparing assignment and bitwise operations.

Comment: @Snowbear Which would be absolutely correct, if it wasn't for the fact that it doesn't seem possible to do a `cmp` or equivilent with a bitwise operator.

Comment: @Polynomial, as an example `b < 128 ? 0 : 128` can be replaced with `b & 128`. That is just an example to convince you. Of course it depends on actual constants.

Comment: @Snowbear I need the output to be `0x00` or `0xff`, regardless of the value of threshold.

Comment: @Polynomial, that is just another values which require another arithmetic operations. Can you try using `b & 128` to check whether it worth trying to get rid of `if` at all?

Comment: @Snowbear Could you clarify please? What bitwise operator will convert 0 to 0 and 128 to 255?

Comment: The solution posted in the question seems to fail for some input values, and takes roughly 3 times as long as the branch.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a bit-wise solution -

```
int intSize = sizeof(int) * 8 - 1;
byte t = (byte)(threshold - 1);
for (....)
{
    data[i] = (byte)(255 + 1 ^ ((t - data[i]) >> intSize));
}
```

Note: Wont work for corner case of 0. Sorry bout that

Also, try using an int array instead of byte and see if it is faster

Comment: It's slower. Using an int array would consume 4x the current amount of memory, too, which is probably a bad idea considering the array is already pretty big. Also, the larger memory allocations will probably slow things down a bit. Thanks for the attempt though.

Comment: Are you sure? 
I just checked for data of int.maxvalue/10 and bitwise seems to take around 890ms vs 1200ms for ternary